# Default Layout Page in ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages, razor

In MVC 3 with Razor view engine, you could establish the default layout page for all of your views.  I can't seem to find a feature like this in ASP.NET razor pages (asp.net web pages with Razor)... anybody know if it exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose a MVC View Master page, see here for screenshots: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-page-layouts-with-view-master-pages-vb

For the new ASP.Net WebPages stuff, its called _PageStart.cshtml (under *~/Shared/* folder). More info here: http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior

Comment: Yes I know, I'm inquiring about the brand-new-with-SP-1 web pages framework, not MVC.

Comment: They need to comeup with better names!

Comment: According to this, _layout is the way to go: http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/3-creating-a-consistent-look or am I missing something?

Comment: I completey agree !! That's not what I'm asking: I know layout pages exist, but in MVC you could set the default layout page in _ViewStart.  THis means every view does not even need to specify the layout because it's established there.  In web pages framework, there is _AppStart, but does not appear to be the same feature.

Comment: Got you! Well, its called `_PageStart.cshtml` (told you they keep changing the names just for the heck of it).  http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior

Comment: Thank you!  I've been through those tutorials, but didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Master pages in regular ASP.NET pages to set a common layout.

Comment: I know I can use a master page (referred to as a layout page) but I'm talking about the brand-new-with-SP-1 web pages framework, which I can define a layout page, but can't globally set it, like I can in MVC, at least I think I can't.